# Cloud9 djangobower install permissions issue

Tags: python, django, bower, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to add the `djangobower` app to my django project in Cloud9.

I changed my `settings.py` as per the instructions from the [documentation](https://django-bower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). But when I try to run `./manage bower install` I get an error:

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/ubuntu/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
>
> You don't have access to this file.

I also tried `sudo ./manage.py bower install`, which gives me:

> bower ESUDO Cannot be run with sudo

And `./manage.py bower install --allow-root`, gives me:

> manage.py bower: error: unrecognized arguments: --allow-root

I'm wondering if this is a weird permissions thing with Cloud9 and if there is some workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [permissions with Bower](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2262), as suggested from the error (not a Cloud9 specific issue).

Use the following to fix it:

`sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm`

`sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config`

Comment: Had to also do `~/.cache`, but that worked! Although, could you explain what exactly those commands are doing / why they're necessary?

Comment: Ya, it's just changing the owner of NPM to your current user (probably `ubuntu` in this case) so you can run commands and install things without needing to be super user. Hopefully that's clear.